# Two menus can't hide the other

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have been reconfiguring my drupal site for faster loading so i restarted from strach, the problem is i can not get rid of the Menu tab which is above the Home tab, if you look at http://beta2.computersuppportservicescs.co.uk you will see what i mean, i have went into the theme setting and untick main menu and seocndary menu and flushed the cache but it is still there.

On http://beta.computersupportservicescs.co.uk you can see i did get rid of it but i think i edit one of the php files directly and commented out the section but i cant remember which one.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting negative votes when it is valid question..., Does anyone know what file stores the information about the displaying of what is on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out again
Look for navigations.css
Edit it and look for menu-toggle
change it from display: none; to visibility: hidden; !important;
now it gone
I will update question with screenshots so others can see the problem better and know what this solution does